# generate token JWT

Tags: node.js, authentication, auth0, express-jwt

I have a problem to generate the token, use the command you passed in tutorial

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer access-token" \
-d '{"foo": "bar"}' \
"https://.cloudfunctions.net/get"
```

When enter in my link /get return " No authorization token found." IT necessary i inform token?

https://github.com/tnguyen14/functions-datastore/

Answer (score 1):

Is your access token, access-token?

A proper jwt format is something like this.

eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.XbPfbIHMI6arZ3Y922BhjWgQzWXcXNrz0ogtVhfEd2o

Comment: I m new using nodejs and JWT, no have knowledge in generate token, 
Can I show you my code

Comment: Sure, you can edit your post! In case, here is my implementation of email/password, fb, google authentication with jwt node.js passport.js (https://github.com/Tetsuya3850/MERN-Examples/tree/master/auth/server) Code to generate jwt is in the models/user.js

Answer (score 0):

Your http request using `curl` looks ok. But I doubt that `access-token` is a valid token. Normally there's some form of `/login` route you need to *obtain* the token, which later on should be provided using the `Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN`.

Comment: I am using nodejs and JWT with google cloud functions create a authentication wiht gcloud deploy

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from https://jwt.io/ where you can specify your `payload` and pass the secret under `VERIFY SIGNATURE` to get a valid `jwt` token. Then you can use this in your `curl` requests.